# copy protecting image viewer

Tags: self-hosted, image-viewer

I'm looking for an android app which

- is an **image viewer** (optionally video) and
- actively **prevents copying** the content which is shown on it. ie.
- no save option,
- **prevents screenshot**,
- does not store files on common storage,
- optionally detects rooted system.

I imagine such an app works like this:

- A content subscriber (user) installs the app.
- The app generetes an assymetric encryption key at installation and
- offers the public part to share.
- The user sends the key to the content publisher.
- The publisher setups a web server where the app downloads encrypted content from (the server part and web server app are not a problem, i can provide it).
- The app navigates to the web site and sends its subscriber ID (say, the encrypting key fingerprint) and
- the server offers content entrypted for the specific instance of the app ie. the specific subscriber.
- In this way I can avoid users access files bypassing the app just via the web site.

Comment: The user can still photograph the screen with a different phone or camera, so it's technically impossible to always "prevents copying the content which is shown"

Comment: @AminDodin, i thought it's obvious. and yes, he can paint it or even memorize. preventing non-technical copy is not in the scope, it's bearable.